# Unable to get response from api and convert it to Json

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning, and It's been few days I've been stuck on this weather app project.

Since i'm new to APIs everything seems so complicated, I'm unable to get response properly from API And this time error I'm getting is **"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"**

My code for reference:

```js
// navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos=>{console.log(pos)});
async function getLoc(){
const apikeyloc = "//apikey//";
const locationapi = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/autocomplete"
let query = document.getElementById("location").value;
const inputbox = document.getElementById("location");
let locationList;

inputbox.addEventListener('keydown',async function(){
    const api = fetch(`${locationapi}${apikeyloc}${query}`);
    
    (await api).json().then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            res.forEach(item => {
                if (item.LocalizedName.indexOf(inputbox.value != -1)) {
                    locationList = `${item.LocalizedName},${item.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName},${item.CountryLocalizedName}`;
                    console.log(locationList)
                }
            });
        })
}

)
    }

getLoc()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <Nav>
        <div class="timezone">
            <div class="city">CityName</div>
            <div class="icon">icon</div>
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Type Location...">
        </div>
        </Nav>

        <div class="weather">
            <div class="temprature">28deg</div>
            <div class="wdesc">Today is Sunny</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check for network tab in dev tools and row response for that request. You will find more info there, you are just reading error that response is not valid JSON, go read what is actual response...

Comment: Avoid sharing your private API key on a public website

Comment: Editing out your privat API-key will still show it in the editing history - might wanna contact a mod..

Comment: using  ```async```makes error handling hard. Try to avoid it till you figured out how it works: https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling.

Comment: @ikiK before I was somehow able to get data somehow when i wasn't using event handler and i had preset value to input using value attribute. I'm not sure how it was working but it worked before, But i had to use event handler because i wanted it to trigger on keydown and Now I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only assign the query variable once, to the document.elementById "location". This is empty at the loading of the page, so every api call you make in the keydown event will be with an empty query, resulting in a blank (non-json) response from the api.

Assign the query variable inside the key event. Also use keyup instead of keydown so that accessing the element's has the correct value. An ajax call on keyup should also be delayed, but take it one step at a time.

```js
// navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos=>{console.log(pos)});
async function getLoc(){
const apikeyloc = "?apikey=Om2MRV8SFRjSuVtjnisRhKGxTNQRzhrL&q=";
const locationapi = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/autocomplete"
const inputbox = document.getElementById("location");
let locationList;

inputbox.addEventListener('keyup',async function(){
    //assign it here.
    var query = document.getElementById("location").value;

    const api = fetch(`${locationapi}${apikeyloc}${query}`);
    
    (await api).json().then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            res.forEach(item => {
                if (item.LocalizedName.indexOf(inputbox.value != -1)) {
                    locationList = `${item.LocalizedName},${item.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName},${item.CountryLocalizedName}`;
                    console.log(locationList)
                }
            });
        })
}

)
    }

getLoc()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <Nav>
        <div class="timezone">
            <div class="city">CityName</div>
            <div class="icon">icon</div>
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Type Location...">
        </div>
        </Nav>

        <div class="weather">
            <div class="temprature">28deg</div>
            <div class="wdesc">Today is Sunny</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because of CORS, external api calls won't work here, no

Comment: CORS issue aside, you hit the api limit with this api key: "The allowed number of requests has been exceeded". Best make a new api key and keep it private.

Comment: yeah it was bacause of limit, plus your original answer also helped So i'll mark it Correct. Thanks for help!